# Browse to HTTPS .svc in IE9 Results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have a WCF service deployed on our test server with the corresponding certificate set up. However, when I try to browse to the service endpoint (e.g., https://myserver.company.com/mywebservice/service.svc) I get a 403 Forbidden error in IE9. But I can get the default page successfully in Chrome and FF.

I'm a little confused and would appreciate it if someone could help me figure out the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error may be because in IE is valid, as IE does not send the client certificate when trying to access the service and hence is forbidden.If you are using IIS to host service make sure you are enable the certificate for the service.